# Use custom font in Flutter package

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I have a project that has the following folders structure:

```
app/
widgets/
```

Where `app` holds the main flutter application and `widgets` is a flutter package that contains reusable components used by `app` and any other project that may want.

I'm trying to use a custom font in one of the widgets placed in `widgets/` folder, but when I run `app` and try to use this widget, the font is not recognized and the Widget title doesn't appear (probably because the font is being incorrectly imported).

I haven't imported the font in `app/pubspec.yaml` (not sure if I should)

I added the custom font to `widgets/assets/fonts` folder and imported in `widgets/pubspec.yaml` like:

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: <FONT_NAME>
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/<FILE>
          weight: 400
```

And I'm using this font in `widgets/<WIDGET>` like this:

```dart
final style = TextStyle(fontFamily: <FONT_NAME>, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, ontSize: 48, height: 48);
....
```

What am I missing in this setup?

OBS: `app/` is an web project, not sure if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it ended up being a problem not related with the font importing...

I was using `height` property from `FontStyle` in `widgets/<WIDGET>` as an absolute value instead a multiplier. E.g: using

```dart
TextStyle(fontFamily: '<FAMILY>', fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 48, height: 48)
```

instead of

```dart
TextStyle(fontFamily: '<FAMILY>', fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 48, height: 1)
```

So the font was being correctly imported, but it wasn't being rendered because the actual height of the font was 48 * 48 = 2304.

The final setup to use `widgets/` fonts in `app/` was:

- Removed the font import from `app/pubspec.yaml`
- Moved the fonts from `widgets/assets/fonts` to `widgets/lib/fonts` -> necessary to the fonts be imported alongside the code source files
- Updated `widgets/pubspec.yaml` to import the files from `lib/fonts` instead `assets/fonts`.

Now, when importing `widgets/` in `app/pubspec.yaml` the custom fonts are working as expected.